# What is the best way to switch between web app's themes with React & Redux?

Tags: css, reactjs, redux, themes, styling

I want to implement an option to switch between two themes in my React and Redux web app.

I have 2 different CSS files, one for each theme. Right now in order to apply a CSS file's stylings, I simply import it at the head of my App.js.

```
import '../styles/theme1.css';

const App = (props) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Container/>
      </div>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    theme: state.settings.theme  // can return 'theme1' / 'theme2'
});

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(App));
```

So I want to import stylings according to the app's state ('theme1' or 'theme2').
I could think of some messy ways and found some ready-made packages for that, but I want to know if there is a conventional way to do so, efficiently and as clean as possible.

this is a create-react-app kit.

Thank you.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: @Paulie_D I edited my question. Please let me know if it is still problematic.

Comment: Is your mismatched single-quote character on line 1 a typo in transcribing your code here? I don't want to "fix" it in case it's part of your problem.  (This is why syntax highlighting is so useful.)

Comment: yep, it was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility depending on how your taskrunner configuration is set up would be to introduce [React-Helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet), which would allow you to change the CSS reference in your `<head>` depending on the theme.

```
import React from "react";
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";

function StyleSwitch (props) {
  return (
    <Helmet>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href={props.stylesheet} />
    </Helmet>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using scss/sass - I think it could simplify the whole process, because it allows you to nest classes/elements.

For example, lets assume you switch between two states, theme1 and theme2:

```
<div className={this.state.theme}>
   <h2>Some text</h2>
</div>
```

And your .scss file should look like

```
.theme1{
   background-color: black;

     h2 {
      color: white;
     }
}

.theme2{
  background-color: white;

    h2{
     color: black;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using scss file requires me to compile it into css. now at my compiled css I am having trouble targeting the body element. .theme1 body { background-color: blue; } for example, won't work.

Comment: You can't nest the body element, as you did .theme1 body {...} - instead try to target body only by the class.

Comment: what do you mean 'target the body only by the class'? how do I target the body and give it different backgrounds for every theme?